# Wrap text inside SVG rectangle. I want to resize the svg rectangle when user tries to enter the text continuously

Tags: svg, image-resizing

I want something like below. Initially there will be a single word when user enters multiple words the size of the box increases. How can I achieve this? Anyone have any idea as to how to proceed on this ?

[image: Initially]

[image: After entering some text]

[image: After entering some more text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the length of the text using http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength 
and then you can resize the rect that depends on the textLength. You can call resize function when onkeydown event fires.

Here is an example of resizing the rect when the text length is changed by interval.

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" ></rect>
    <text x="20" y="40">123</text>  
</svg>

<script>
    var textElement = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
    var rectElement = document.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];

    resizeRect();

    setInterval(resizeRect, 1000);

    function resizeRect(){
        textElement.textContent += 0
        var textLength = textElement.getComputedTextLength();
        rectElement.setAttribute("width", 50 + textLength)
    }

</script>
```

You can find a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0dvu604g/

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I am looking for. Can I new line the text after certain characters ??

Comment: You can read about multiple lines of text in SVG here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#Introduction

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.